# How do I get values from a table out of a foreach loop?

Tags: php

What I'm doing is trying to set up a page where users can see their created tools and delete them whenever they want.  I'm querying three different tables and putting the results into an array.  Once those values are in an array, a foreach loop goes through and populates a table with all the information in a table, like so:

```
    $counter = 1;
    echo '<table>'
    foreach ($recent_saved_tools as $key => $value) {

            echo '<tr name="item'.$counter.'">';
            echo '<td>';

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="tablename" value="'.$value['table'].'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="tabledelete" value="'.$value['delete'].'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="tableidfield" value="'.$value['idfield'].'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="tableid" value="'.$value['id'].'" />';

            //code to display the tool name and link
            echo '<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="'.WEBSITE.'tools/'.$value['URL'].'?saved_data_id='.$value['id'].'">'.$value['display'].'</a><br />';
            echo date("m/d/Y H:i:s", $key).'<br />';
            echo '</td><td>';

            //code to display the delete button
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="cssformbutton bluebutton" type="button" name="delete" id="deletebtn'.$counter.'" value="Delete" /><br /><br /><br /><br /></td>';

            $counter ++;

    }
    echo '</table>';
```

The problem is whenever I run the SQL query, no matter what button I click it always takes the values from the last table row.  I know it has something to do with the way they're named (multiple elements have the same name) but I'm at a loss on how to fix this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the query I'm using to delete the item:

```
$query = 'UPDATE '.$value['table'].' SET '.$value['delete'].' = 1 WHERE '.$value['idfield'].' = '.$value['id'];

$sql->query($query);
```

EDIT: added delete code

Comment: show us your delete code?

Comment: can you also indicate how you determine `$value` for your delete query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every row has some inputs which are posted to the server. They have the same names - for every row. You could change it like this:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="tablename'.$counter.'" value="'.$value['table'].'" />';
```

Then you can use `$_POST['tablename'.$rownr]` in your delete code.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're closing the  anywhere...

What results return from the query?
What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

try making it a for loop in stead and adding the variable to the end.

```
    $array;
    $counter = count($array);
    echo '<table>'
    for($i = 0; $i < $counter - 1; $i++) {

        echo '<tr name="item'.$i.'">';
        echo '<td>';

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="tablename" value="'.$value['table']. $i'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="tabledelete" value="'.$value['delete']. $i'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="tableidfield" value="'.$value['idfield']. $i'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="tableid" value="'.$value['id'].'" />';

        //code to display the tool name and link
        echo '<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="'.WEBSITE.'tools/'.$value['URL'].'?saved_data_id='.$value['id'].'">'.$value['display'].'</a><br />';
        echo date("m/d/Y H:i:s", $key).'<br />';
        echo '</td><td>';

        //code to display the delete button
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="cssformbutton bluebutton" type="button" name="delete" id="deletebtn'.$counter.'" value="Delete" /><br /><br /><br /><br /></td>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: the edit causes a loop that will never begin as `$i` will equal `$counter`

Comment: I have used that very code myself many times and it has never failed me.

Comment: you may have used something 'similar' but this code is wrong. If you're going to change the functionality, change the items to make it a better example of how it could be implemented.

Comment: you were right I forgot to change the count to reflect the array size, thanks for the catch.